# How do I delay the movement of object after each movement

Tags: processing, collision-detection, move

I am making frogger. I want to use a grid system for the movement of the "baddies". The player character moves 64 pixels each time a key is pressed. I want the enemy characters to move 64 pixels one time then a delay then move one time and repeat.

My code having the enemy characters and the "goodie" pickup spawn in a random place within the grid is not working either. If you could help with that, that would be great.

You do not have to show me how to fix it in my code, I just need to know how to do it, meaning if you want to make a basic code for it, that would be preferred.

```java
    //variables
    float froggerX;// frogger position on the x axis
    float froggerY;// frogger position on the y axis
    int speed = 64; //frogger moves its entire area
    int baddieXspeed = 2; //baddie speed X
    int NUM_GOODIES = 3; //number of goodies spawned
    int NUM_BADDIES = 4; //number of baddies spawned
    float []baddiesX; // baddies X pos
    float []baddiesY; // baddies Y pos
    float []goodiesX; // goodies X pos
    float []goodiesY; //goodies Y pos
    int gridSize = 64; //grid size factor
    int columns; // columns of grid
    int rows; // rows of grid
    float[] gridX = {16, 80, 144, 208, 272, 336, 400, 464, 528, 592, 656}; //goodies location X pos
    float[] gridY1 = {80, 144, 208, 272, 336, 400, 464, 528, 592, 656}; //goodies location Y pos
    float[] gridY = {64, 128, 192, 256, 320, 384, 448, 512, 576}; //baddies location pos
    
    
    void setup() {
      size(576, 768); // size of window
      baddiesX = new float[NUM_BADDIES];
      baddiesY = new float[NUM_BADDIES];
      goodiesX = new float[NUM_GOODIES];
      goodiesY = new float[NUM_GOODIES];
      columns = width/gridSize;
      rows = height/gridSize;
      placeFrogger();// calling function void placeFrogger()
      placeGoodies(); //calling function void placeGoodie()
      placeBaddies(); //calling function void moveBaddie()
    }
    void draw() {
      background(0); //color of background = black
      smooth(); //anti-aliasing
      noStroke();
      grid(); // calling function void grid()
      drawFrogger(); // calling function void drawingFrogger()
      restrictFrogger(); // calling function void restrictFrogger()
      makeFroggerWrap(); // calling function void makeFroggerWrap()
      drawGoodies(); //calling function void drawGoodie()
      drawBaddies(); //calling function void drawBaddie()
      moveBaddies(); //calling function void moveBaddie()
      //collisionBaddie();
      collisionGoodie();
    }
    
    /*
     * drawFrogger - draws frogger at the given x, y
     */
    void drawFrogger() {
      froggerHead();
      froggerEyes();
      fill(0);
      rect(froggerX+12, froggerY+36, 40, 8);
    }
    void froggerHead() {
      fill(193, 154, 107); //tan
      rect(froggerX, froggerY, 64, 64); //head
      fill(92, 64, 51); //brown
      rect(froggerX, froggerY, 64, 16); //hair
    }
    
    void froggerEyes() {
      fill(255); //white
      rect(froggerX+12, froggerY+20, 12, 12); //left eye white
      fill(255); //white
      rect(froggerX+40, froggerY+20, 12, 12); //right eye white
      fill(92, 64, 51); //brown
      rect(froggerX+14, froggerY+22, 8, 8); //left eye iris
      fill(92, 64, 51); //brown
      rect(froggerX+42, froggerY+22, 8, 8); //right eye iris
      fill(0); //black
      rect(froggerX+16, froggerY+24, 4, 4); //left eye pupil
      fill(0); //black
      rect(froggerX+44, froggerY+24, 4, 4); // right eye pupil
    }
    
    void placeFrogger() {
      froggerX = 256;
      froggerY = 704;
    }
    
    void keyPressed() //what i used to make frogger jump 64 pixels
    {
      if (key == 'w') //move up
      {
        froggerY = froggerY - speed;
      }
      if (key == 's') //move down
      {
        froggerY = froggerY + speed;
      }
      if (key == 'a')//move left
      {
        froggerX = froggerX - speed;
      }
      if (key == 'd')//move right
      {
        froggerX = froggerX + speed;
      }
    }
    /*
     * restrictFrogger - do not advance frogger when hitting top/bottom
     */
    void restrictFrogger() {
      if (froggerY < 0) {
        froggerY = froggerY + 64;//top barrier
      }
      if (froggerY > 704) {
        froggerY = froggerY -64;//bottom barrier
      }
    }
    
    /*
     * makeFroggerWrap - puts frogger on left when it reaches right,
     * right when left
     */
    void makeFroggerWrap() {
      if (froggerX < 0) {
        froggerX = froggerX + 576;//left wrap
      }
      if (froggerX > 512) {
        froggerX = froggerX - 576;//right wrap
      }
    }
    void drawGoodies() { //draws goodie/ it is like an exp bubble in minecraft
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<NUM_GOODIES; i++) {
        ellipseMode(CORNER);
        fill(32, 178, 170); //bluegreen
        ellipse(goodiesX[i]-16, goodiesY[i]-16, 64, 64); //outer circle
        fill(0, 255, 127); //limegreen
        ellipse(goodiesX[i]-8, goodiesY[i]-8, 48, 48); // middle circle
        fill(212, 175, 55); //gold
        ellipse(goodiesX[i], goodiesY[i], 32, 32); // inner circle
      }
    }
    void placeGoodies() {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<NUM_GOODIES; i++) {
        goodiesX[i] = gridX[i]; //places goodie at random Y pos
        goodiesY[i] = gridY1[i];  // places goodie at random Y pos
      }
      for (i=1; i<NUM_BADDIES; i++) {
      }
    }
    void drawBaddies() { //draws a zombie from minecraft
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<NUM_BADDIES; i++) {
    
        fill(0, 255, 100); //lime green
        rect(baddiesX[i], baddiesY[i], 64, 64); //head
        fill(0, 155, 100); //dark green
        rect(baddiesX[i], baddiesY[i], 64, 16); //hair
        fill(0); //black
        rect(baddiesX[i]+8, baddiesY[i]+20, 12, 12); //left eye
        fill(0); //black
        rect(baddiesX[i]+44, baddiesY[i]+20, 12, 12); //right eye
      }
    }
    void placeBaddies() {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<NUM_BADDIES; i++) {
        baddiesY[i] = gridY[i];  // places baddie at random Y pos
        baddiesX[0] = random(512, 576); //places baddie at edge of screen
        baddiesX[1] = random(640, 704); //places baddie 64 pixels outside of screen
        baddiesX[2] = random(768, 832); //places baddie 128 pixels outside of screen
        baddiesX[3] = random(896, 960); //places baddie 196 pixels outside of screen
      }
    }
    
    void moveBaddies() {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<NUM_BADDIES; i++) {
        baddiesX[i] = baddiesX[i] - baddieXspeed;
        if (baddiesX[i] < -64) {
          baddiesX[i] = random(576, 704);//wraps baddie at random x value outside of screen
          baddiesY[i] = gridY[i]; //when baddie wraps, baddie gets new Y values
        }
      }
    }
    
    void collisionBaddie() {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<NUM_BADDIES; i++) {
        if (froggerX <= baddiesX[i]) {
          if (froggerY <= baddiesY[i])
            froggerX = 256;
          froggerY = 704;
        }
      }
    }
    void collisionGoodie() {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<NUM_GOODIES; i++) {
        if (froggerX <= goodiesX[i] && froggerY <= goodiesY[i]) {
          goodiesX[i] = 1000;
        }
      }
    }
    void grid() {
      for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) { //columns going down
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) { // rows going to left
          int gridx = i*gridSize;
          int gridy = j*gridSize;
          fill(0, 255, 200); //background color
          stroke(0); //line color
          rect(gridx, gridy, gridSize, gridSize);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could go about doing this:

A) Build a little timer, and have it count down from X. Once it hits 0, all your baddies move and the timer resets.

```
//global variables
int baddieMoveTimer = 30
int baddieMoveTimerMax = 30;

void draw(){
  baddieMoveTimer -=1;
  if(baddieMoveTimer == 0){
     moveBaddies();
     baddieMoveTimer = baddieMoveTimerMax;
  }
}
```

By default, processing runs at 60 frames per second. You can adjust this. In the code above, the baddies will wait half a second between moves.

B) There is a built in variable call FrameCount that tracks how many times draw has been called since the start of the program. You can use this as a shortcut to the above process:

```
void draw(){
   if(FrameCount % 30 == 0){
     moveBaddies();
   }
}
```